# WPF - Bind Orientation property to DockPanel.Dock in ItemsPanelTemplate's StackPanel

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I'm building a CustomControl that inherits ItemsControl and have a StackPanel for ItemsPanelTemplate.
This is the Style:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type MyCustomControl}">
      <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Path=DockPanel.Dock, Converter={StaticResource PositionToOrientationConverter}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
               <Grid >
                  <Border Background="Black" Height="0"/>
                  <ItemsPresenter/>
               </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
```

And this is the converter Class:

```
   Public Class PositionToOrientation
  Implements IValueConverter

  Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
     Dim position As Dock = value
     Select Case position
        Case Dock.Top
           Return Orientation.Horizontal
        Case Dock.Bottom
           Return Orientation.Horizontal
        Case Dock.Left
           Return Orientation.Vertical
        Case Dock.Right
           Return Orientation.Vertical
     End Select
     Return Dock.Top
  End Function

  Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
     Throw New NotImplementedException
  End Function
   End Class
```

But it seems to ignore the orientation property.

EDIT: The functionality that I want to obtain is that when i put MyCustomControl in a DockPanel, the StackPanel is oriented according to docking(like i coded in the Converter).

Comment: You are currently binding to a `DockPanel.Dock` property of the data item class. Is that your intent? Besides that, "I can't get it working" is not a very helpful error description. Try to add more details to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sorry but it's my first question here. I edited the question to clear my intention.

Comment: Are there any error/binding messages in the debug output?

Comment: No error or messages. I create a program in wich I put MyCustomControl in a DockPanel. But if I set DockPanel.Dock=Top  for MyCustomControl, the items in it are arrenged vertically instead of horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need any converter to achieve the desired result. Just add a StackPanel Style with two DataTriggers for the `DockPanel.Dock` attached property for the `Top` and `Bottom` values.

The bindings in the DataTriggers use the ItemsControl as their `RelativeSource` and put the property path in parentheses because it's an attached property.

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(DockPanel.Dock), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                         Value="Top">
                                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(DockPanel.Dock), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                         Value="Bottom">
                                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want to obtain. Trying to do it I'm focusing on binding and don't consider trigger. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Note that you could of course also directly bind the StackPanel's Orientation with your converter, but you would also need to add the RelativeSource and put the Path in parentheses.